# check equality of list of dictionary values

Tags: list, dictionary

what` the wrong here
in want to check if values are equal the print the key

```
id1 =[{'ahmed':[1,2,3,5]},{'nora':[1,2,3]}]
id2=[{'y':[1,2,3,5]},{'x':[1,4,6]}]


for i in range(len(id1)):
    if (id1[i].values()==id2[i].values()):
        print(id1.keys(),id2.keys())
    else:
        print ("not same ")
```

Comment: What output are you getting?  What is the question?  Add a tag for language.  It looks like Python.